# Document Templates - Roles Set to In person or email signing

Tags: docusignapi

I have successfully created a system to use a document template to create a new envelope.

The system has a tabbed UI and iframe that fetches new URLs from the Docusign API every time a tab is changed, and when a URL expires.

**My problem is** that now, some clients will either be sign in-person or sign via email.  After reading the docs, I don't see a way to change from an in-person to an email signer after the envelope has been created.  **Is that correct?**

- Is it possible to set whether a role will be in-person or email sign at the time of envelope creation, without affecting the original template?
- If that is not possible, Is my best option to create a template with duplicate fields for both in-person and email signing, and only use the appropriate ones based on my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to change an in-person signer to a remote signer, or vice-versa, or any other recipient type into another recipient type you have two options:

1. Perform an Envelope Correction
2. Remove then Add the Recipient back to the in-process envelope as a different type.

---

For option #1, using an envelope correction you can edit things like recipients, tabs, and even documents if they have not been signed yet. Make the following API call to request the correction URL of an envelope:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/correct
```

API Docs:  https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createCorrect/

---

For option #2, the system does not let you convert a recipient into another recipient type - HOWEVER - you can delete a recipient from an envelope then add them back in as a different type. For instance, delete an in-person signer and then add them back in as a signer.

You can see the needed calls through the [EnvelopeRecipients Resource](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/).

Comment: I'm looking in the Node API wrapper and wondering if it is capable of doing this or if I need to write the POST myself. 

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/c84772c4fb2fcf1e890adde6f96067986520f573/src/model/CorrectViewRequest.js#L22

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/c84772c4fb2fcf1e890adde6f96067986520f573/src/api/EnvelopesApi.js#L3034-L3042

Also curious if there are any recipes or code samples that feature this - I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Looks like the second option is going to give us more flexibility and control to do this within our own UI.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any recipes for changing recipient types or doing corrections, we'll try to create some soon.