# createRecipient call throwing 'No recipients specified' error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on changing a signer's role type.  To accomplish this I'm deleting the signer from an envelope, then re-adding them to the envelope with a different signingGroupId.

To accomplish this, I am doing the following:

```
    const newClientRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();

    newClientRole.setName(signerName);
    newClientRole.setEmail(signerEmail);
    newClientRole.setRoleName(opts.clientUserId);
    newClientRole.setClientUserId(opts.clientUserId);
    newClientRole.setSigningGroupId(opts.contact.futureRoleGroup);

    newClientRole.setDefaultRecipient(signerEmail);
    newClientRole.setInPersonSignerName(signerName)

    console.log('newClientRole', newClientRole);

    envelopesApi.createRecipient(accountId, pair.envelopeId, newClientRole, (err, data, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      return cb(null, data);
    })
```

However, when I do this I get:

```
 error:
  { [Error: cannot POST /restapi/v2/accounts/<MY ACOUNT ACCOUNT ID>/envelopes/0dbc5905-0aa2-4005-8455-ae50332dd803/recipients (400)]
    status: 400,
    text: '{\r\n  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",\r\n  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. No recipients specified."\r\n}',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/restapi/v2/accounts/<MY ACOUNT ACCOUNT ID>/envelopes/0dbc5905-0aa2-4005-8455-ae50332dd803/recipients' },
```

I'm not sure what to do about this, since I definitely specify a recipient.  I was worried that I wasn't instantiating newClientRole correctly, so I log it out and it looks ok:

```
  newClientRole TemplateRole {
  email: '<OUR ACTUAL EMAIL>',
  roleName: 'client1',
  name: 'Edward Wu',
  signingGroupId: 'signers',
  inPersonSignerName: 'Edward Wu',
  clientUserId: 'client1',
  embeddedRecipientStartURL: null,
  defaultRecipient: '<OUR ACTUAL EMAIL>',
  accessCode: null,
  routingOrder: null,
  emailNotification: null,
  tabs: null,
  constructFromObject: [Function],
  getEmail: [Function],
  setEmail: [Function],
  getRoleName: [Function],
  setRoleName: [Function],
  getName: [Function],
  setName: [Function],
  getSigningGroupId: [Function],
  setSigningGroupId: [Function],
  getInPersonSignerName: [Function],
  setInPersonSignerName: [Function],
  getClientUserId: [Function],
  setClientUserId: [Function],
  getEmbeddedRecipientStartURL: [Function],
  setEmbeddedRecipientStartURL: [Function],
  getDefaultRecipient: [Function],
  setDefaultRecipient: [Function],
  getAccessCode: [Function],
  setAccessCode: [Function],
  getRoutingOrder: [Function],
  setRoutingOrder: [Function],
  getEmailNotification: [Function],
  setEmailNotification: [Function],
  getTabs: [Function],
  setTabs: [Function],
  toJson: [Function] }
```

I've included the entire error text here: https://gist.github.com/dzoba/e9e1619ae6924efb440e20535b210661

I also turned on logging API calls in the Docusign admin, and see the request (with recipient) coming through there.  This is what the log downloaded from Docusign says:

https://gist.github.com/dzoba/e9bb9e8e2c3399d61291024559d41e9e

Comment: If I POST directly to the API, I can make it work, if I structure the body like this: https://gist.github.com/dzoba/aaa6f6f91341aba548215d17ebf36367 

However, I'm not sure why the node API isn't formatting it like this (since I did 'newClientRole.setSigningGroupId').  Going to try doing it manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [API logging info](https://gist.github.com/dzoba/e9bb9e8e2c3399d61291024559d41e9e) you posted, the reason for the error is that your request body is missing the (top-level) **signers** attribute -- an array that contains an object for each signer you want to add.  So, in your scenario (adding a single signer), the request body should contain an [EnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#/definitions/EnvelopeRecipients) object like this:

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
          "email": "<OUR ACTUAL EMAIL>",
          "roleName": "client1",
          "name": "Edward Wu",
          "signingGroupId": "signers",
          "inPersonSignerName": "Edward Wu",
          "clientUserId": "client1",
          "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
          "defaultRecipient": "<OUR ACTUAL EMAIL>",
          "accessCode": null,
          "routingOrder": null,
          "emailNotification": null,
          "tabs": null
        }
    ]
}
```

DocuSign is returning the *No recipients specified.* error message because it looks for recipients inside the [EnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#/definitions/EnvelopeRecipients) object's top-level attributes (i.e., **agents**, **carbonCopies**, **signers**, etc.) -- because your request body does not contain any of those top-level attributes, DocuSign is unable to recognize the request body as containing any recipients.

---

EDIT #1

---

So, now I understand that your scenario is that you want to change a recipient from "sign in-person" to "sign remotely via email".  To do this, you must delete the original recipient from the Envelope and then add a new recipient to the Envelope (just as you've indicated in your comment below).

The code for adding a new Recipient (Signer) to an Envelope will look something like the following.  Keep in mind that the new Recipient will have no tabs by default -- you must specify any/all tabs for the new Recipient (the sample code below specifies a single *SignHere* tab).

```
// add a recipient to sign the document
var signer = new docusign.Signer();
signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
signer.setName(signerName);
signer.setRecipientId('1');

// create a signHere tab somewhere on the document for the signer to sign
// default unit of measurement is pixels, can be mms, cms, inches also
var signHere = new docusign.SignHere();
signHere.setDocumentId('1');
signHere.setPageNumber('1');
signHere.setRecipientId('1');
signHere.setXPosition('100');
signHere.setYPosition('100');

// can have multiple tabs, so need to add to envelope as a single element list
var signHereTabs = [];
signHereTabs.push(signHere);
var tabs = new docusign.Tabs();
tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
signer.setTabs(tabs);

// add recipients (in this case a single signer) to the envelope
envDef.setRecipients(new docusign.Recipients());
envDef.getRecipients().setSigners([]);
envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().push(signer);
```

(This code sample originated from [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.js).)

Comment: Nice!  Looks like I stumbled onto the same thing in my comment on the original question. 


I restructured the data to look more similar to that, now sending my newClientRole variable in an array as the value to a signers key in an object.


I now get 'The request contained at least one invalid parameter. \'recipientId\".  The nodejs docusign API doesn't appear to offer a function to set the recipientId.  Is it incomplete?  Should I just structure the JSON myself?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to add a new signer to an existing (either draft or in-progress) Envelope?  If that's the case, then I don't think you'll want to do so by using "TemplateRole" (as your code shows) -- instead, I'd think you'd want to simply create a new Recipient (Signer).

Comment: Of course, if you go this route (create an entirely new recipient), keep in mind that the new recipient would not have any of the tags that the deleted recipient (which was based upon a template role, assuming the envelope was originally created from template) had.

Comment: I'm trying to change a signer from 'in person' to 'sign via email'.  I was doing that by deleting the recipient, then re-adding it with a different signing type.  I got the idea from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38447184/935473 and hopefully I'm following the instructions correctly?

Comment: That's the correct procedure to use for changing a recipient from an in-person signer to a remote (sign via email) signer -- i.e., you do indeed need to delete the original recipient, then add a brand new recipient.  I will edit my answer momentarily to add more info about how I suggest you go about this using Node.js.

Comment: Thank you!  Its so great that Docusign monitors SO.  Really invaluable.